# GCD: return on non-main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I use `dispatch_async` in some non-main thread. Let's call it "thread A". I got thread A not by using GCD. After executing some block I want to return in thread A. How can I make it?

tread A:

```
dispatch_queue_t fetchQ = dispatch_queue_create("Thread B", NULL);
dispatch_async(fetchQ, ^{
    // Do some stuff...
    // ...

    //Now I want to return in Thread A
});
dispatch_release(fetchQ);
```

Comment: The sooner you make the distinction between "threads" and "queues" the better off you are going to be.  Don't fool yourself into believing that you are guaranteed to run on the same thread just because you used the same GCD queue.

Comment: Sorry, it was really stupid question. Thank you @borrrden

Comment: I didn't say it was a stupid question, I just thought that you should be aware of the distinction before you start considering answers.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
dispatch_queue_t fetchA = ...
//..

dispatch_queue_t fetchQ = dispatch_queue_create("Thread B", NULL);
dispatch_async(fetchQ, ^{
    // Do some stuff...
    // ...

    dispatch_async(fetchA, ^{
        // Do stuff on Tread A
    });

});
dispatch_release(fetchQ);
```

Comment: The question notes that OP got the first "thread" (not sure if that's what he really has) via methods other than GCD.  Perhaps you could convince him to do it this way (I hope) but for now this misses the mark a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of an ugly way of doing it, but it seems to work.

```
dispatch_queue_t fetchQ = dispatch_queue_create("Thread B", NULL);

__block BOOL changeWhenComplete = NO;

dispatch_async(fetchQ, ^{

    for (int i =0; i < 2; i++) {

        NSLog(@"doing work");
        sleep(1);
    }
    //Now I want to return in Thread A
    changeWhenComplete = YES;
});
dispatch_release(fetchQ);

while (!changeWhenComplete) {

    sleep(1);
    NSLog(@"waiting for fetchQ to complete");
}

NSLog(@"fetchQ returned");
return;
```

Its worth noting that this will block thread A.